# Is is possible to access VB .net APIs in Python

Tags: python, vb.net

I am new to programming in Python, I was wondering if there is a way to access VB .net APIs using Python.

Please let me know
thanks in advance.
VG

Comment: Hmm... somehow probably. If you are using IronPython, definately, just a matter of referencing them. My question is, why?

Comment: Once a .net dll is compiled to an assembly, doesn't matter what language the source is, it's all MSIL at that point, so they're freely interoperable (dependent of course on the .net runtime version the lib was compiled against).

Answer (score 6):

## Python for .NET

Python for .NET is a package that gives Python programmers nearly seamless integration with the .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR) and provides a powerful application scripting tool for .NET developers.

Using this package you can script .NET applications or build entire applications in Python, using .NET services and components written in any language.